# Rails 5 Using delegates with many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delegates

I've been struggling to find the right approach for this.
I have a many-to-many relationship between User and Group associated through a Membership.

The Membership model also has an attributed call 'status' that reflects the current membership status i.e. a user assoicated with a group maybe bronze, silver or gold status.

I've been having trouble accessing the status in a sensible way, without lots of queries, and figured there must be a more efficient way.  I started with delegates but couldn't get that to work.

e.g. here is the code

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end
```

group.rb

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

membership.rb

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  enum status: [ :bronze, :silver, :gold ]
end
```

Now in the 'show' view for a group, I want to show all the users who are members, so I do this:

```
<% @group.users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.memberships.find_by_group_id(@group.id).status %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This works, but as I have already retrieved a specific instance of the user via the group memberships, it would be nice if I could directly reference the status for that user, without having to search through the memberships again.
If possible maybe using an instance method or delegate, so that I can effectively call user.status

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple

```
<% @group.memberships.each do |membership| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= membership.user.id %></td>
    <td><%= membership.user.email %></td>
    <td><%= membership.status %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: To avoid the `n+1` problem I would make this `@groups.memberships.includes(:user).each do`